# Finding vector form of an angle bisector in a triangle

Tags: triangles, vector-analysis

[image]

Find vector form of angle bisector, $\vec{BP}$, using $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$.

[image]

That's how far I've got. Please don't use $tb+ (1-t)b$, or similar since I don't know what that is. Just basic dot product, vector product, triple product...If possible.

Comment: what are you trying to find, exactly? you have the direction of the bisector - are you trying to find the length of AP?

Comment: I will post an answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: $k=\frac{|b||c|}{|b|+|c|}$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27381/discussion-between-david-quinn-and-desperado).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\overrightarrow{AP}=k\left(\frac{\underline{c}}{|c|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow\overrightarrow{BP}=-\underline{c}+k\left(\frac{\underline{c}}{|c|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right), \text{and}$$
$$\Rightarrow\overrightarrow{PC}=\underline{b}-k\left(\frac{\underline{c}}{|c|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow\overrightarrow{BP}\text{ is parallel to }\overrightarrow{PC}\Rightarrow-\underline{c}+k\left(\frac{\underline{c}}{|c|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)=\alpha\left(\underline{b}-k\left(\frac{\underline{c}}{|c|}+\frac{\underline{b}}{|b|}\right)\right)$$
Since $\underline{b}$ and $\underline{c}$ are independent, we can equate coefficients and solve simultaneously to find $k.$

After a couple of lines, we get $$k=\frac{|b||c|}{|b|+|c|}$$

Comment: I have underestimated the  equation. What coefficients?

Comment: write out the coefficients of $\underline{b}$ and $\underline{c}$ separately, forming a simultaneous equation, and eliminate $\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\vec{c}|$ / $|\vec{BP}|$= $|\vec{b}|$ / $|\vec{CP}|$ we can express length of $|\vec{BP}|$ using familiar vectors, and then just add the vectors.